# ASP.NET MVC 2 Input ID

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-4.0

Adding the following to my view:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="newBookingRef" name="newBookingRef" />
```

Results in the following HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="MainContent_newBookingRef" name="ctl00$MainContent$newBookingRef">
```

If I use the helper method Html.Textbox, the ID is generated as I would expect "newBookingRef".

How can I stop it prefixing the ID on standard input controls with the content placeholder id? I tried playing with the ClientIdMode of the content placeholder but this didn't seem to help.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the runat="server" attribute.

Comment: doh! I can't believe I didn't spot that. More coffee needed I think :)